# CrmServiceClient is always returning null Organization Service

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-365-sales

I've got the following code to connect to Dynamics 365 Online organization. It throws a null reference exception on `orgService.Execute(new WhoAmIRequest());` and error log is below the code. I've tried this on two machines with different console apps. I've tried both the 8.2 and 8.0 SDK DLLs. If I rewrite this using `CrmConnection` with the 7.x SDK DLLs everything works fine. I can browse to the organization using the same credentials (cut & pasted to be sure there is not a typo.)

The connection string format is taken from the example at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt608573.aspx:

> Named account using Office 365
>
> `<add name="MyCRMServer"
>   -connectionString="AuthType=Office365;Username=jsmith@contoso.onmicrosoft.com;
>   Password=passcode;Url=https://contoso.crm.dynamics.com"/>`

The basic code.

```cs
var connectionString = @"Url=https://ORGNAME.crm.dynamics.com; Username=username@ORGNAME.onmicrosoft.com; Password=43JF##$j#@Ha; Authype=Office365;";

var client = new CrmServiceClient(connectionString);            

var orgService = (IOrganizationService)client.OrganizationWebProxyClient ?? client.OrganizationServiceProxy;

orgService.Execute(new WhoAmIRequest());
```

Error log output:

```
Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient Information: 8 : Discovery URI is = https://ORGNAME.crm.dynamics.com:443/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc
Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient Information: 8 : DiscoverOrganizations - Initializing Discovery Server Object with https://ORGNAME.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc
Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient Verbose: 16 : DiscoverOrganizations - attempting to connect to CRM server @ https://ORGNAME.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc
Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient Error: 2 : Source  : System.ServiceModel
Method  : Retrieve
Date    : 2/13/2017
Time    : 5:42:37 PM
Error   : Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://ORGNAME.crm.dynamics.com/_common/error/errorhandler.aspx?BackUri=&ErrorCode=&Parm0=%0d%0a%0d%0aتفاصيل الخطأ: The service '%2fXRMServices%2f2011%2fDiscovery.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Crm.Site.Services%2c Version%3d8.0.0.0%2c Culture%3dneutral%2c PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..&RequestUri=%2fXRMServices%2f2011%2fDiscovery.svc%3fwsdl%26sdkversion%3d8.1&user_lcid=1025'.
Stack Trace : at System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient.MetadataRetriever.Retrieve(TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient.ResolveNext(ResolveCallState resolveCallState)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient.GetMetadata(MetadataRetriever retriever)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient.GetMetadata(Uri address, MetadataExchangeClientMode mode)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceMetadataUtility.RetrieveServiceEndpointMetadata(Type contractType, Uri serviceUri, Boolean checkForSecondary)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfiguration`1..ctor(Uri serviceUri, Boolean checkForSecondary)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateManagement[TService](Uri serviceUri, Boolean enableProxyTypes, Assembly assembly)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateManagement[TService](Uri serviceUri)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmWebSvc.CreateAndAuthenticateProxy[T](IServiceManagement`1 servicecfg, Uri ServiceUri, Uri homeRealm, ClientCredentials userCredentials, ClientCredentials deviceCredentials, String LogString)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmWebSvc.DiscoverOrganizations(Uri discoveryServiceUri, Uri homeRealmUri, ClientCredentials clientCredentials, ClientCredentials deviceCredentials)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmWebSvc.DiscoverOrganizations(Uri discoveryServiceUri, Uri homeRealmUri, NetworkCredential networkCredential)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmWebSvc.InitCRM2011Service()
======================================================================================================================
Inner Exception Level 1 : 
Source  : System.Runtime.Serialization
Method  : ThrowXmlException
Date    : 2/13/2017
Time    : 5:42:37 PM
Error   : CData elements not valid at top level of an XML document. Line 1, position 3.
Stack Trace : at System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowXmlException(XmlDictionaryReader reader, XmlException exception)
   at System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.Read()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient.MetadataLocationRetriever.GetXmlReader(HttpWebResponse response, Int64 maxMessageSize, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas readerQuotas)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient.MetadataLocationRetriever.DownloadMetadata(TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient.MetadataRetriever.Retrieve(TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper)
======================================================================================================================

Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient Error: 2 : Unable to Login to Dynamics CRM
Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient Error: 2 : OrganizationWebProxyClient is null
Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient Error: 2 : OrganizationServiceProxy is null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried passing the parameters directly to the CrmServiceClient instead of the connection string?

I can connect successfully to Dynamics365 by using this following method

```
public CrmServiceClient(string crmUserId, SecureString crmPassword, string crmRegion, string orgName, bool useUniqueInstance = false, bool useSsl = false, OrganizationDetail orgDetail = null, bool isOffice365 = false);
```

And here's how I applied

```
var pwd = ConvertToSecureString("userpassword");
CrmServiceClient client = new CrmServiceClient("user@mail.com", pwd, "NorthAmerica", "orgname", isOffice365: true);
```

And here's the method to convert the password to secure string

```
private System.Security.SecureString ConvertToSecureString(string password)
{
    if (password == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("missing pwd");

    var securePassword = new System.Security.SecureString();
    foreach (char c in password)
        securePassword.AppendChar(c);

    securePassword.MakeReadOnly();
    return securePassword;
 }
```

Comment: That method certainly works, thanks for posting it. It still doesn't resolve why the connection string method, which is documented in the SDK, is not working. I'm trying to figure out if I did something wrong or if it is a bug. The issue becomes in my real-world app I prefer to get the connection string from the config file - as that eliminates having to figure out what type of connection I'm making and passing the correct parameters.

Comment: I figured it out. I have a type in the `connectionString`. It should have been __authtype__ and I have __authype__. That said, your answer actually got me there and deserves the credit - declaring the authentication type as an explicit parameter helps eliminate this issue.

Comment: Glad you find the root cause :)   .. btw that was a typo kind of hard to notice at first instance lol.

Answer (score 3):

As per latest Microsoft recommendation we are not supposed to use “AuthType=Office365”.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/authenticate-office365-deprecation

We can use Application Account (Client ID & Secret Key) to generate Token & access Dynamics CRM Organization Service. But if you want to use User ID & PWD then Use (AuthType = OAuth)

Sample Code :

```
string connectionString = "AuthType = OAuth; Url = 'https://*****.crm.dynamics.com'; Username = '*******'; Password = '*******'; AppId = 51f81489-12ee-4a9e-aaae-a2591f45987d; RedirectUri = app://58145B91-0C36-4500-8554-080854F2AC97;LoginPrompt=Never";

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

CrmServiceClient crmServiceClient = new CrmServiceClient(connectionString);
WhoAmIResponse whoAmIResponse = crmServiceClient.Execute(new WhoAmIRequest()) as WhoAmIResponse;
```

Note : While trying to use this from Azure Function I got below errors :

1. ERROR REQUESTING Token FROM THE Authentication contextNeed a non-empty authority
2. One or more errors occurred. => An error occurred while sending the request. => The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. => Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. => An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote hostERROR REQUESTING Token FROM THE Authentication context
3. CurrentAccessToken = 'crmServiceClient.CurrentAccessToken' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'

Easily you can resolve these using just one additional line  :    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Ref URL : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4051700
Microsoft Dynamics 365 Customer Engagement (online) to require TLS 1.2 for connectivity

Pls let me know if you are facing any other issues.

Thanks,
Sumit

Comment: This works for me "ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting error

```
Unable to login to Dynamics CRM, Error was :                    
Data[0] = "The provided uri did not return any Service Endpoints!
```

I received this error when attempting to connect to Dynamics using a connection string with AuthType=ClientSecret. Previously I was connecting successfully using username and password with a connection string of the form

```
"Url={dynamicsConnectionString};Username={username};Password={password};AuthType=Office365;"
```

The connection string was changed to have the form

```
"AuthType=ClientSecret;RequireNewInstance=false;Url={CrmDynamicsPrivatePrimaryConnection};ClientId={CrmDynamicsPrivateClientId};ClientSecret={CrmDynamicsPrivateClientSecret};LoginPrompt=Never;"
```

The error occurred because I was using an outdated version of `Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly`. I was using version `9.0.2.27`, and according to a web report, version `9.1.0.13` is needed for connecting with ClientSecret. I updated to version `9.1.0.68` using NuGet, and the Dynamics connection worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling on fixing this issue because everything I did except installing higher version (On MS docs also They didn't mentioned this) of **Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly** since lower version of this dll doesn't support **ClientSecret** authentiation.